# Linux Group ACLs for FileServer Proxmox Container

Tags: linux, acl, proxmox

I've installed a LXC fileserver on Proxmox Server to share a 1TB volume via NFS and CIFS and have it working with a set of user and group.

Group: authors
Users:

- Alicia
- Lisa
- Henrik
- Lars

Group: contractors

- Jens
- Soren

Group: external

- external_vendor
- api_user
- dropbox

I have these shares:

```
/companyName/media/release
/companyName/media/drafts
/companyName/media/proofs
/companyName/media/shared
```

authors can

- rw - release
- rw - drafts
- rw - proofs
- rw - shared

contractors can

- r  - release
- rw - drafts
- rw - proofs
- r  - shared

external can

- r  - release
- r  - shared

I have apply the permission on the group authors to the above folders via Samba but I cannot figure out how to apply a second group to the folders.

We need to let anyone that can write to those shares to be able to delete each others things as well. Ive been reading about ACL but trying lots of things from chowning groups to users does not seem to work the behaviour I was seeking above.

This is on a small NAS we have in the office. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

(you omitted to tell us what you had tried and why it didn't work).

The "read list" and "write list" permissions in Samba use a comma separated list:

```
[release]
...
read list = @contractors, @external
write list = @users

[drafts]
...
read list = @external
write list = @contractors,@users

[proofs]
...
read list = 
write list = @contractors,@users

[shared]
...
read list = @contractors
write list = @users
```

Note that these are not "linux" ACLs - these are security controls implemented by Samba. You mentioned NFS in your post but it is far from clear if you are also offering the same shares via NFS or if the LXC is acting as a SMB/NFS bridge (since you also mention a "NAS"). i.e. these ACLS will not impact the behaviour of NFS.

I am hesitant to suggest an approach to achieving the same result via NFS in the absence of a lot more information about how the network security is configured.